# How do I mixdown multiple audio channels in java/xuggler?

Tags: java, audio, channel, resampling, xuggle

like mixing 6 channel surround down to stereo? xuggler throws: ERROR com.xuggle.xuggler - Error: inputChannels > 2; unsupported

Answer (score 1):

The Xuggle provided resampler can only do stereo or mono.  You'll need to write your own resampler, but you can use the IAudioSamples.getData(...) methods to get access to the raw data to do your own resampling and mixing.